# Laptop RDP LAN only works when laptop is connected to another VPN

Tags: vpn, remote-desktop, lan

So for the life of me I can not figure out why I have this weird issue.

I have a desktop and laptop at home. When the laptop is connected to VPN ( External work network ) I can rdp to it just fine. Now when it should be even easier to connect to only connected to my router and no VPN for some reason I can't ping it, I can't RDP into it.

It's connected to WiFi with no manual DNS settings or anything like that. Firewall is disabled completely, only the VPN connection has firewall rules set externally.

Router 192.168.2.1 ( ASUS RT-AC68U )
Desktop 192.168.2.100 ( ESET Firewall RDP allowed )
Laptop 192.168.2.159 ( No firewall )

Comment: Tell us more about your local network and where are situated the RDP client and server.

Comment: Desktop is EoP LAN connected to router and Laptop is WiFi connected, both have an IP reservation in DHCP. I mean it works just fine while the laptop is VPN connected.

Comment: VPN connected to what? Is the Laptop also on that VPN?

Comment: The VPN is connected to business network at&t vpn. on a completly different range. The desktop is not connected to the vpn. The rdp from desktop to laptop only works when the laptop is on vpn

Comment: Is this the classical problem of accessing your home from work?

Comment: Nope the weird part is I cant access the local lan laptop disconnected from VPn but it's on local lan my home router. So I shouldnt need vpn to access it as the router can still see it if it's on VPN or not because their both connected to the same home router. However some how rdp o ly works while the laptop is connected to vpn to the work network completly separate from my home network.

Comment: Please add to your post a schema of your architecture (because what you are saying seems impossible). Include the local DHCP server and all IP addresses of all devices, when connected to VPN or not.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out the firewall was turning on when I disconnected from VPN which is strange because it showed as off for all connection types (domain, private and public) while connected to VPN.